# Sandbox IP mapping not working on HDP Sandbox

Tags: macos, hadoop, hortonworks-data-platform, hortonworks-sandbox

I have downloaded the latest HDP 2.6.5 from Hortonworks website. Following the instructions in the section 'MAP SANDBOX IP TO YOUR DESIRED HOSTNAME IN THE HOSTS FILE
' from the  link -

https://hortonworks.com/tutorial/learning-the-ropes-of-the-hortonworks-sandbox/#determine-ip-address-of-your-sandbox

I added the details to the hosts file. When I try the site sandbox.hortonworks.com or any of the ones mentioned in the mapping, I get the error 'Site can't be reached'.

I am using Macbook and running the Sandbox on VirtualBox. I am able to log on to the command line using the url http://localhost:4200 and Ambari via http://localhost:8080/#/login.

I just want to know why I am not able to get it working using sandbox.hortonworks.com

Comment: If localhost works, you'll be fine. Sometimes you need to reboot for the hosts file to start working

Comment: By reboot do you mean, I need to restart my macbook or restarting the HDP Sandbox? I had done both. I had sent power off signal to HDP sandbox and restarted it. It didn't work.

Comment: I mean reboot the host machine, but `sudo vim /etc/hosts` should work after you save the file. It's not clear what you're using as the IP for the sandbox

Comment: I did the reboot but to no avail. I am using 10.0.2.15 as the IP address while adding to the /etc/hosts file. Basically I see this as an issue because following this tutorial - https://hortonworks.com/blog/hands-on-tour-of-apache-spark/ when I run the last command for count, I get the error saying Unknown Host Exception - sandbox.hortonworks.com. So, if I get this fixed am hoping it would resolve many issues later on without having to worry about the internals.

Comment: The code in that tutorial is running Spark inside of the VM, not from a Mac terminal, and if you run `ifconfig` on the VM, it should show the real IP, which you need to cross-verify with the `/etc/hosts` file

Comment: It is showing multiple ip's. I have now run the command you asked in the VM terminal using root user. I see two sections, UP LOOPBACK RUNNING and UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST. I now put one of the ip from MULTICAST in the etc/hosts file. It's not working. Should I be restarting my Mac?

Comment: If you edit the `/private/etc/hosts` of the Mac, then maybe, but again, that tutorial isn't using the Mac terminal, so no network requests wouldnt be coming from it. The Sandbox should *already have* the correct hosts file internally, so you shouldn't need to edit that. Your very first link seems to walk you through what information you need to get. But still, Spark is not required to use the sandbox's host address. It can use an IP instead. All the tutorials can, AFAIK, so it would be better to understand what can change, then fix it for your environment, rather than blindly follow the guides

Comment: is it a typo sandbox-hdp.hortonworks.com ?

Answer (score 1):

Just add the port after your link:

```
sandbox.hortonworks.com:4200
```

or

```
sandbox.hortonworks.com:8080
```